# Sudo reboot -f hangs

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I do `sudo reboot -f` the server reboots, but the terminal just says "rebooting" and doesnt exit out.  I have to actually press `ctrl-c` to have it exit.  Is there a way to get the server to exit out without me pressing `ctrl-c`.  Also I have to use `sudo reboot -f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `sudo reboot -f`, the operating system performs a *fast reboot*: the kernel does the minimal necessary actions to shut down without severe filesystem corruption. In a fast reboot, proper termination of processes, including `sshd`, is considered unimportant. The scheduler just stops giving processes any more execution time as the kernel concentrates on a quick flush of the disk caches and any other kernel-level shutdown actions.

(As a result, some files may be left open. However, on modern journaling filesystems, these things are normally fixable by the quick filesystem check at boot time, as far as the filesystems are considered. But files with important internal structures, like databases, may be left in an inconsistent state. If so, they will likely need application-specific recovery actions... Lesson: **Don't use `reboot -f` unless absolutely necessary.**)

Meanwhile, your remote access client will be left hanging: from its viewpoint, the server sent one last message "Rebooting"... and then there was no response at all. No SSH connection termination, not even a TCP FIN. Just silence.

The client will follow the normal TCP retry rules. This can take several minutes, during which nothing visible happens... but all that time, the OS of your client system is trying again and again to resend any outgoing packets your remote access client may have sent after the reboot command.

If the server takes a long time to self-test and restart, the connection will eventually time out as the TCP stack of the client OS gives up trying and reports an error to the remote access application. This will typically take several minutes.

But if the server reboots quickly, when it reaches the point where it will activate its network interfaces again, the server's OS will see the incoming packets from your remote access client. Then the server will consult its freshly-initialized table of active network connections, conclude that there is no record of such a connection, and send back a TCP Reset. When your client receives that, only then it will report that the connection has been forcefully terminated.

Comment: that is an awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is running into issues during the shutdown process, check the contents of /var/log/messages and/or /var/log/syslog for more information and update your original post.

EDIT: I saw your note saying that the reboot works just fine, but you don't disconnect from the server. I'd make sure that your SSH timeout settings aren't set too high locally: https://bjornjohansen.no/ssh-timeout

Comment: no, it reboots just fine.  The issue is I have to press ctrl-c or eit out of the terminal.

Comment: Updated my answer